# Align list item to the same line

Tags: html, css

Using this layout: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/JBuE6/6/

On the top right I want the green button to site on the same line as the H1 tag on the right side, and so that every new list item sits to the side of the next time.

I think this might be something to do with:

```
display:block
```

I haven't been able to get this to work and I dont know if this is even the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the UL before the H1 and you should be in good shape, e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Create New</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Create New2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Create New3</a></li>
 </ul>
 <h1>Title</h1>
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/52raq/3

Answer (score 0):

If you want a right aligned item to be the same height as a left aligned item you need to put it BEFORE the left aligned item. That should take care of it.